# How to inject service that is using injection token using injector in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I'm developing a package that is used by two projects in my company.
In project A and only there we got a message service that is provided in `core.module` like this:

```
        {
          provide: 'MESSAGE_SERVICE',
          useClass: MessageService
        }
```

In my component, I need to inject this service. I'm doing it using `injector`. However the method `get` that accepts a string as a parameter is deprecated so I cannot use it, although it works. When I try to use a new API with `InjectionToken` I always get undefined.
Here's my code:

```
  protected messageService: any;

  constructor(protected injector: Injector) {
    const messageServiceInjectionToken = new InjectionToken('MESSAGE_SERVICE');
     // i get null
    this.messageService = this.injector.get<any>(messageServiceInjectionToken, null, InjectFlags.Optional);
    // It works but method is deprecated
    this.messageService = this.injector.get('MESSAGE_SERVICE', null);
    // It works but I cannot use MessageService class directly as it is not present in application B
    this.messageService = this.injector.get(MessageService);
  }
```

What is the proper way to get my service without using direct imports of said class? 
I thought of creating a mock class in project B so I would be able to use `MessageService` class. However, I'd like to know if there's a better way.

*EDIT*

The shared service is just a base class to other implementations, it is provided using a factory so there's not dependency injection in it.
This is how it is provided:

```
export function parentServiceFactory(platformService: PlatformService, injector: Injector) {
  if (platformService.isIOS) {
    return new IosChildService(injector);
  }

  if (platformService.isAndroid) {
    return new AndroidChildService(injector);
  }

  return new DesktopChildService(injector);
}

@NgModule({
providers: [
    {
      provide: ParentService,
      useFactory: parentServiceFactory,
      deps: [PlatformService, Injector]
    }
]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of that injection token is to be able to not use the injector.

Instead =, use this syntax

```
constructor(@Inject('MESSAGE_SERVICE')protected service: YourInterface)
```

Although if you make a service, I don't see the point of using an injection token.

Comment: I'd like to avoid this approach as my class is inherited by other classes. That's why I am using a injector.

Comment: And how does that prevent you from using this approach, or the default one with `@Injectable` ?

Comment: It does not it is just mundane work to pass message service to parent component in every child

Comment: @karoluS so what prevents you from using this method or the default one again ?

Comment: I've made an edit to the original question explaining why it would not work in my scenario.

Comment: @karoluS and **_AGAIN_**, how does that prevent you from using the default syntax ? You do not need the injector to inject it, all you need is a common interface between all of your services.

Comment: It just does not work because there is no dependency injection in parent service nor child services.

Comment: @karoluS and again, that isn't an issue at all.

Comment: @karoluS I give up. It seems like you're creating your own issues and you don't want to resolve them. I'm not wasting anymore time, good luck with that issue, I hope you find a solution !

Answer (score 0):

You can create an angular library and then use it in any number of projects

Here's how to create an angular2 library https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2017/how-to-create-an-angular-library

with angular-cli https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Comment: It would not work in application B where `MessageService` is not available.

Comment: Consider upvoting the answers that are the same as the one you are about to write, as per SOF best practices